# jquery to take in the typed text in a textarea and pass it to a backend handler (perl, php, etc..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a very simple 'textarea' in html:

```
<div id="textarea">
<textarea rows="20" cols="45" autofocus wrap>
</textarea>
</div>
```

With 2 buttons:

```
<div class="buttonbox">
<a class="button" href="#"><span id="spButton">Solve Problems</span></a>
<a class="button" href="#"><span id="pmfButton">Pull My Finger</span></a>
</div>
```

I am trying to understand the jQuery to allow the button 'spButton', when pressed following text entered into the 'textarea', to be captured and passed, in a var to the backend, in my case perl.  I have seen/tested some XHR handler cases for image transfer, and they work fine, but thought that simple text would be far more... well... simple? I am not able to grab the typed text at all, only the static text that I had placed within the 'textarea' tags? Clearly I am missing something.

In the following attempt, I am not able to extract the 'var' to even print the text entered in an alert:

```
$(function() {
$('#spButton').click(function() {
var inText = $('textarea#textarea').val();
alert(inText);
});
});
```

The above, while appearing to be syntactically(questionable) correct, does not return any typed text from the 'textarea' to the alert, it is simply a bank alert popup with 'undefined' as the text?  I have also tried '.text()' however that only grabs any text encapsulated within the 'textarea' tags.  You can get a look at what I have done so far (very little) here:  https://github.com/gmconklin/zephyr

Apparently I need a rep to post pics? Hmm nonsensical, but I cannot provide screenshots due to this limitation, apologies.

Thanks for any assistance.

-G

Comment: You really should not use as attribute ID 'textarea' for a DIV element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
var inText = $('textarea#textarea').val();
```

That means a textarea with id textarea.

What you want is a textarea inside a div with id textarea.  That is this:

```
var inText = $('#textarea textarea').val();
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot, ugh... I so over complicate everything. Apologies for this being so trivial.  thanks again!